# EaselJS Is it possible to modify a Spritesheet at runtime?

Tags: easeljs

I am loading spritesheets individually for each sprite on demand using PreloadJS.  Some of the spritesheets don't have certain animations (I lack the images). I would like to use a "Default Image" if the spritesheet doesn't contain a particular animation.

It would be ideal if I could add the Default Image to the spritesheet at runtime and that way when gotoAndPlay("Missing Animation") is called the Default Image will be available instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not natively implemented in EaselJS, but it should be easy for you to implement it yourself.

Instead of appending a image to the original bitmap that was used as the spritesheet source image, you can make your own `gotoAndStop` function, and check if the image exists or not by checking if `mySprite.spritesheet.animations.indexOf("Missing Animation Name")` is less than zero. If it is, display a bitmap object containing the default image you want.